# AI platform install dependencies each time a version is called

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I have a timeout problems with model calls for predictions that seems to be because of cold start.
It appears that the model's node is installing the dependencies nearly each time it's called (while there is a minNodes to 1). The problem occurred only if there is more than 1 version, else it's not reinstalling dependencies and it's predicting in 1s rather than doing a timeout of 120s...
Do I need to put a higher minNodes or something?

If anyone had the problem and have a solution (or any recommandation) I'm really interested ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to see if I understood your issue: you are using AI Platform model and the nodes install the dependencies each time it is called. When there are more than one version, it does not reinstall dependencies and does a quick prediction.

In order to continue, I need to ask you the following questions:

- What is the error that you are given? Do you have any relevant messages on the logs?
- What type of dependencies do you have? In case you have a training application, you may have different types of dependencies (standard and custom) [3].
- When you refer to versions, are you talking about model versions in AI Platform or to the different versions for the dependencies?

Regarding the minNodes when trying to predict, I do not think that increasing this number will solve the issue. According to [1], in case the load is higher, it will add more nodes and then scale down, at least, minNodes. Having at least two nodes, you will be covered by the SLA [2], but probably facing the same issue.

[1] -
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.models.versions#autoscaling

[2] -
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#create_a_model_version

[3] -
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#working_with_dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The dependencies are reinstalled only if there is more than one version of the model. If there's only one version everything goes fine.
- There is no error at all in the logs, I just have a timeout error at execution because of the dependencies reinstallation.
- only standard dependencies
- I refer to the model versions.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue and the dependencies are not installed twice even when I have several versions. I understand that you are using the old AI Platform, have you tried migrating your models to Vertex AI [1]?

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai

Comment: On the other hand, I have checked if there is any way to extend the timeout on AI Platform but I haven't found much. Only this PIT [1] for requesting a timeout, although we cannot provide an ETA for this.
Please, star the issue so you can get mail notifications every time there is an update in the Feature Request [3]. Also, the more stars the Feature Request has, the more likely is to be implemented [4].

Comment: [1] https://issuetracker.google.com/147084050
[2] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests
[3] https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue
[4] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#what_to_expect_once_youve_opened_an_issue

Comment: Hi @Malaman and thank you for your comments. Yes we're using AI platform and not Vertex AI yet. I'm trying to find any more information to give context on my problem but there isn't much more to say which makes the problem so strange...

Comment: we kind of resolved our problem by doing an autodelete on old version when releasing a new model's version and thus always having only one version of the model. It's a temporary solution